# CONTEXT struct P/Invoke declaration in C# is wanted

Tags: pinvoke

Does anyone has the P/Invoke declaration of the CONTEXT struct defined in the WinNT.h file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PInvoke.NET](http://pinvoke.net/) is a free Visual Studio plugin that inserts P/Invoke signatures automatically.

Another useful tool is [P/Invoke Interop Assistant](http://www.codeplex.com/clrinterop).

Answer (score 1):

```
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct CONTEXT
    {
        public uint ContextFlags;
        public uint Dr0;
        public uint Dr1;
        public uint Dr2;
        public uint Dr3;
        public uint Dr6;
        public uint Dr7;
        public FLOATING_SAVE_AREA FloatSave;
        public uint SegGs;
        public uint SegFs;
        public uint SegEs;
        public uint SegDs;
        public uint Edi;
        public uint Esi;
        public uint Ebx;
        public uint Edx;
        public uint Ecx;
        public uint Eax;
        public uint Ebp;
        public uint Eip;
        public uint SegCs;
        public uint EFlags;
        public uint Esp;
        public uint SegSs;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=0x200, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public byte[] ExtendedRegisters;
    }
```